# What's the benefit of a fixture with function scope and no teardown code?

Tags: python, pytest

What's advantage of a (default) function-scope fixture without teardown code? Why not just call the function at the beginning of the test?

For example, what's the benefit of writing:

```
@pytest.fixture
def smtp():
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")

def test_ehlo(smtp):
    response, msg = smtp.ehlo()
    # ...
```

instead of simply:

```
def create_smtp():
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")

def test_ehlo():
    smtp = create_smtp()
    response, msg = smtp.ehlo()
    # ...
```

I understand why fixtures are useful when we need teardown code. I also understand why fixtures with scope other than function are useful: we may want to reuse the same "external" object in multiple tests (to save the time it takes to create it; or perhaps even to maintain its state -- although that seems to be rather dangerous since this creates an hard-to-see coupling between separate tests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar question when I started using it. Here's my experience:

- Fixtures can be set to `autouse=True`, i.e., trigger automatically that may not be possible with an inline call. This is useful in some cases.
- Fixtures add readability, at least for me. Looking at the signature of the test, one can figure out what initialisations are a pre-requisite for a given test. In that sense, it also help keep the test and it's initialisation isolated.

Comment: Yes, I guess putting all "external" objects into a signature of a test serves as a kind of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> What's advantage of a (default) function-scope fixture without
>   teardown code? Why not just call the function at the beginning of the
>   test?

Saving vertical space.

Consider something like this, where you have more than one fixture per test:

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def value1():
  return 1

@pytest.fixture
def value2():
  return 2

@pytest.fixture
def value3():
  return 3


def test_values(value1, value2, value3):
    assert value1 == 1
    assert value2 == 2
    assert value3 == 3
```

If we were to do this your way:

```
def test_values():
    v1 = value1()
    v2 = value2()
    v3 = value3()

    assert v1 == 1
    assert v2 == 2
    assert v3 == 3
```

That's three extra lines of code. Not a big deal, but then what if you had 10 tests that needed `value1`, `value2` and `value3`? Now you have 30 extra lines of vertical space for basically no reason.

Obviously, both of our examples are overly simplified (I could just have done the call and `assert` inline), but I think it's straightforward to see how this could have an impact with real code.

Comment: That makes sense, although I think less than half of tests that require a fixture need more than one of those.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one of the most important advantage of function-scoped fixtures is consistency. It is much more readable and logical if all your fixtures (no matter of they scope or tear-down code) are used in exactly same way.

Also if in some point in future you'll decided to change the scope of this fixture or to add some tear-down code to it then you would not need to change any test cases, only the code of the fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636207/11277611
I'm not so liking fixtures, but one advatage - it's reusability.
If you have some function with long computtion - you can define it once in fixture and reuse it every time in the tests.
Surely you can do this with a regular function, IMO, it's a kind of test.