# How to best structure conftest and fixtures in across multiple pytest files

Tags: python, pytest, conftest

Let's say I have 3 lists of DataFrames containing different data that I want to run the same test cases on. How do I best structure my files and code so that I have one `conftest.py` (or some sort of parent class) that contains all the test cases that each list needs to run on, and 3 child classes that have different ways of generating each list of DataFrames but run the same test cases?

This is how I am currently constructing it.

```
import pytest

class TestOne:
    
    # this method usually takes 10 mins to run
    # so we want this to run once and use the same Dict for all test cases
    dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("one")

    def test_dfs_type(self):
        assert isinstance(self.dfs, dict)

    def test_another_one(self):
        assert ...
```

`dfs` will not be modified throughout the test suite, so I want to treat this like a setup.

`TestTwo` and `TestThree` are the same thing except it will be `get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("two")` and `get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("three")`

Any tips on how to efficiently structure this would be appreciated!

Comment: This is what fixtures are for. You set up `dfs` once and then re-use it for multiple tests. See: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html and also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376252/when-to-use-pytest-fixtures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you need to run the same test case but with different data you can use the `parametrize` function.
So, let's say this is you test:

```
def test_dfs_type():
        assert isinstance(dict)
```

And you need to run it 3 times. One for each data frame you have.
To do that you can put all the data you need into a list.
But first, let's create the classes (I've simplified them a bit):

```
# classes.py
class ClassOne:
    # this method usually takes 10 mins to run
    # so we want this to run once and use the same Dict for all test cases
    # dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("one")
    dfs: dict[str, str] = {'one': 'class one value'}


class ClassTwo:
    # this method usually takes 10 mins to run
    # so we want this to run once and use the same Dict for all test cases
    # dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("two")
    dfs: dict[str, str] = {'two': 'class two value'}


class ClassThree:
    # this method usually takes 10 mins to run
    # so we want this to run once and use the same Dict for all test cases
    # dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("three")
    dfs: dict[str, str] = {'three': 'class three value'}
```

Now, let's create the file with tests:

```
# test_classes.py

import pytest
from classes import ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree


DATA_FRAMES = [ClassOne.dfs, ClassTwo.dfs, ClassThree.dfs]


@pytest.mark.parametrize('data_frame', DATA_FRAMES)  # Here we create a parameter "data_frame" that will give one object from a list at each test run.
def test_dfs_type(data_frame):  # And here is the arguments we indicate that the test waits for that parameter.
    print(data_frame)  # Print data just to see what happens in each test
    assert isinstance(data_frame, dict)
```

The result is:

```
>> pytest -v -s
test_classes.py::test_dfs_type[data_frame0] {'one': 'class one value'}
PASSED
test_classes.py::test_dfs_type[data_frame1] {'two': 'class two value'}
PASSED
test_classes.py::test_dfs_type[data_frame2] {'three': 'class three value'}
PASSED
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to have a parent class that contains all the test cases and any child class who extends the parent class would automatically run all the test cases?

Comment: I am not sure but I think pytest handles classes just as tests grouping. So it doesn't support inheritance. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a `fixture` and defining the [scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes) to the desired `fixture`s life time with `session` being the the one that is generated once for the entire testing session.

In the following code the `dfs` is created only once for the entire testing session and all the test can use it.

```
from typing import Dict

import pandas as pd
import pytest


def get_list_of_dfs_somewhere(text: str) -> Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]:
    return {
        "one": pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]}),
        "two": pd.DataFrame({"b": [1, 2, 3]}),
        "three": pd.DataFrame({"c": [1, 2, 3]}),
    }


# conftest.py
# this method usually takes 10 mins to run
# so we want this to run once and use the same Dict for all test cases
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def dfs() -> Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]:
    return get_list_of_dfs_somewhere("one")


# test_dfs.py
def test_dfs_type(dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]):
    assert isinstance(dfs, dict)


def test_another_one(dfs: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]):
    assert ...
```