# pytest fixture vs global variable

Tags: python, pytest

I know that when multiple tests use the same variable, it should be defined as a fixture, so that it gets initialized once, and can be re-used.

What I don't understand, however, is what advantage it offers (apart from looking cleaner) over a simple global variable, that also gets initialized once, and is accessible to all tests as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62376252/2745495

Answer (score 0):

Fixtures are meant to avoid using global variables in the first place, they are meant to provide resources to test functions that are isolated and particular for each test.

I think that best to understand it is using the functionality "scope" that fixture provide

Answer (score 0):

The advantage comes with more complicated test inputs, test data, and test setups. Fixtures make for more *predictable* test cases, because you can manage your fixtures' setup and teardown, as well as making sure they have the correct *scope*.

For example, let's say you have an app that reads and updates JSON data. That means you'll want to have tests that accepts some input data, sharing the same input data across all the tests, but at the same time making sure that each test doesn't influence each other.

For example:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def test_data() -> dict:
    data = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
    yield data

def test_update_a_plus_1(test_data):
    update_a(test_data)
    assert test_data["a"] == 2

def test_update_a_plus_8(test_data):
    update_a(test_data)
    assert test_data["a"] == 9

def test_update_a_times_5(test_data):
    update_a(test_data)
    assert test_data["a"] == 5
```

If you used a global variable for `test_data`, then those tests would fail because the value of `"a"` gets updated after each test run. You would think that you can write code to define `test_data` instead at the beginning of *every* test that needs it so that they are localized to that test. But then,... you've just duplicated test code. You could then think of writing a function that defines `test_data`, returns it, then calling that function on *every* test case. While that works for "simple" test data like this, that wouldn't work for relatively complex test data like input files and database entries, because if the test fails, unless it's in a fixture, you'll have manually manage the cleanup of the test data yourself. As described in the pytest docs:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization

> When we run our tests, we’ll want to make sure they clean up after themselves so they don’t mess with any other tests (and also so that we don’t leave behind a mountain of test data to bloat the system). Fixtures in pytest offer a very useful teardown system, which allows us to define the specific steps necessary for each fixture to clean up after itself.

There's also the point about scope. Let's say part of your tests requires input data by setting-up a local database and filling in tables with some test data, which can be an expensive/slow operation. You'd want to only do that setup once for a certain set of tests. But then what if you had tests that updated the data in the DB? That could then affect the other tests. So maybe you'd want to re-setup your test env for each of those write tests. This kind of situation is easily managed by pytest's scope: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/how-to/fixtures.html#fixture-scopes.

For example, your read tests only needs to setup the test data once for the entire module:

```
# test_read.py

# Only need to set this up once, since all the tests are just reading the data
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def setup_test_data():
    setup_db()
    yield
    clean_db()

def test_read_one():
    ...

def test_read_multiple():
    ...
```

Then for your write tests, you can set the fixture scope to be ran per function:

```
# test_write.py

# Make sure the test data is reset and clean on every test case
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setup_test_data():
    setup_db()
    yield
    clean_db()

def test_write_then_read():
    ...

def test_delete_all():
    ...
```

Managing scope and setup/teardown like cannot be down with simple global variables. You will unnecessarily write code just to manage the test environment/data, which is something that pytest fixtures already does for you.